# minikube deployment of mysql failed... image pull failed .. ubuntu environment

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, deployment, proxy, minikube

I am trying to deploy a mysql in minikube cluster. but it is failing because it failed to pull image from dockerhub registry.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:latest
        name: mysql
```

But surprisingly, when I am trying to deploy my own developed image in same minikube it is deploying properly

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: xxx
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: xxx
      version: 'v1'
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: xxx
        version: 'v1'
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: opaapp
          image: registry.hub.docker.com/***/xxx:latest
```

Not able to understand what need to be configured to deploy MySQL in minikube

Comment: what is there you are getting? Maybe internet connectivity is a problem? Are u able to reach google from the minikube Kubernets node?

Comment: yes .. if i do  following ..i am getting response back  ..1)  minikube ssh 2) curl www.google.com .. then why it is not able to reach dockerhub for MySQL image

Comment: Thanks again .. may be some problem with my network .. now it is able to pull image.. created the pod .. but failed for some other reason .. let me check

Comment: What kind of error did you get? Please provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you are using latest version of minikube, and skipping the network related errors, I tried to deploy your manifest in minikube v1.11.0 and I see the following:

```
2020-06-05 11:48:44+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: Database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
    You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

If you change your yml file to:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:latest
        name: mysql
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
          value: "True"
```

you should good to go.